# what kind of attack can be work by using two different secret key

Tags: encryption, secret-key

Consider the following simple protocol intended to allow an RFID reader to authenticate an RFID tag. The protocol assumes that the tag can store a 32-bit secret key, s, shared with the reader, perform XOR operations, and receive and transmit via radio 32-bit values. The reader generates a random 32-bit challenge x and transmits y = x ⊕ s to the tag. The tag computes z = y ⊕ s and sends z to the reader. The reader authenticates the tag if z = x.

as we know same secret key can be encrypt and decrypt the same value message but if we use two different secret key how can it work????

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [security](http://security.stackexchange.com), without involving programming

Comment: Exactly what are your asking about, here? How to attack the described scheme? Or how to modify the scheme to resist the attack? Where, exactly, does this exercise come from, and is there some specific part of it that you're stuck with?

Comment: as i ask we know that same secret key can be encrypt and decrypt by two side...but if we get two secret key is it can perform same attack?? if not then what kind of attack should we use?

Answer (score 0):

This scheme cannot work if the keys don't match. Usually some kind of key derivation is used on the reader side though, using some kind of identifier broadcast by the tag.

```
K_tag = KDF(K_master, ID)
```

Even then, you can only use this to authenticate the tag, and that *only once*, assuming that sniffing out the communication is possible. With the protocol you describe you can easily sniff out the two values and then XOR out the key of the tag. XOR does not provide a high level of security within the protocol you've described.

Comment: I'm just answering here because I lost all confidence in the SO method of handling migration.

Comment: as paragraph above shows we know XOR method can be use to solve when using same secret key to encrypt and decrypt the reader and tag...
but for the different key as u say we need use some kind of identifier broadcast then what kind of identifier we can use??

Comment: Can the same attack works if the tag and reader share two secret keys s1 and s2, the reader sends x ⊕ s1 and the tag responds with x ⊕ s2 after recovering x? If not, what kind of
attack will work?